# Some of the references in my bib file are not appearing when I compile the file. In-text citation are with a question mark

Tags: bibliographies

I am using TeXstudio to write my thesis and I am getting issues with my .bib file. All the reference are in the bib file that I compiled from Mendeley. The issue is that some in-text citations appear as a question mark and they also don't appear in the bibliography even when I use \nocite{*}. When I compile this in Overleaf I don't get such error.

My .bib file looks like this:

```
@article{Legras2010,
abstract = {We measured high-contrast visual acuity (VA)},
author = {Legras, Richard and Benard, Yohann and Rouger, H{\'{e}}l{\`{e}}ne},
doi = {10.1016/j.visres.2010.04.001},
issn = {00426989},
journal = {Vision Research},
keywords = {Aberrations,Adaptive optics,Multifocal contact lenses,Numerical simulation},
number = {12},
pages = {1185--1193},
publisher = {Elsevier Ltd},
title = {{Through-focus visual performance measurements and predictions with multifocal contact lenses}},
volume = {50},
year = {2010}
}
@techreport{cha,
author = {Charman, W N},
title = {{OPTICS OF THE EYE}}
}
```

...

And this is my document class:

```
 \documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,titlepage,oneside,final]{book}
```

Does anyone know how to overcome this issue?

Comment: have you run bibtex as well as latex since updating your bib file?

Comment: Yes I did, but still the same problem

Comment: The entries you posted have no obvious syntax errors that could explain their not appearing in the bibliography or citations. As David says you need to run LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX on your document (where LaTeX can be your favourite flavour of LaTeX: pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, XeLaTeX, ...). If entries can't be found there should be a message about that in the `.blg` file: Check it. (On Windows machines you may have to unhide file extensions to find the file. Windows will also wrongly classify the `.blg` as 'performance monitor file', but it is just a text file you can open with any text editor)

Comment: You have not provided any code that reproduces your problem so it is more or less impossible to guess what is wrong.  Run bibtex on the document and show the bibtex log (blg) file, look for any errors reported.

Comment: overleaf runs bibtex for you so in the absence of any other problem shown not running bibtex at the right time is the most likely difference between running it at overleaf and running it locally.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your help! I used to only use overleaf so I was not familiar that I had to run bibtex (and did not know how to do so but now I see its pretty simple). When I run bibtex I get several warnings like "empty publisher in Artal2017, empty institution in Burns2"  and that is why these citations were skipped. I will fix that and I believe this should work. I apologize for the simplicity of this question. Now I know to always run bibtex, something that now seems so obvious.  Thank you so much for your help!